# JAXB namespaces and prefix

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm having an issue when unmarshalling the following XML:

```
<p456:doServiceResponse xmlns:p456="http://www.sign.services.org/IServicios/">
    <respuesta>0</respuesta>
    <respuesta>Operacion correcta</respuesta>
    <respuesta>respuesta</respuesta>
</p456:doServiceResponse>
```

I have the following class:

```
package com.ws.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "respuesta" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "doServiceResponse")
public class DoServiceResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> respuesta;

    public List<String> getRespuesta() {
        if (respuesta == null) {
            respuesta = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.respuesta;
    }

}
```

And package-info file:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.sign.services.org/IServicios/",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.ws.client;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

The unmarshalling of that XML doesn't fail, but `respuesta` field is `null`. If I add `p456` as prefix to all `<respuesta>` nodes, then it works. The thing is I can't do this since that is the answer I receive from a WS call and is not modifiable.

Also, to not break anything, I'll post the "request" to that WS, which is working fine so far:

```
<doServiceRequest xmlns="http://www.sign.services.org/IServicios/">
    <aplicacion>app</aplicacion>
    <params>param1</params>
    <params>param2</params>
</doServiceRequest>
```

And the bean:

```
package com.ws.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "aplicacion", "params" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "doServiceRequest")
public class DoServiceRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String aplicacion;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> params;

    public String getAplicacion() {
        return aplicacion;
    }

    public void setAplicacion(String value) {
        this.aplicacion = value;
    }

    public List<String> getParams() {
        if (params == null) {
            params = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.params;
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me how to configure the annotations so I'll be able to unmarshall both XMLs without modifying them and without touching the JAXB unmarshaller? Would that be possible?

Comment: I guess it is because you have `xmlns:p456="http://www.sign.services.org/IServicios/"` as namespace. It would work without `p456` if your namespace is like `xmlns:"http://www.sign.services.org/IServicios/"`

Comment: @user2004685 You mean on the first XML, doServiceResponse? That's how the WS returns the response, so I can't modify it.

Comment: Are you using the same set of Schemas both the sides? I mean the Request as well as the Response?

Comment: @user2004685 Yeah, they are using the same Schema. Both classes have been generated from the WSDL by using `wsimport`. I've updated the Schema, since I added the `xmlns` prefix manually for my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a namespace argument to the @XmlElement annotation:

```
@XmlElement(required = true, namespace="")
protected List<String> respuesta;
```

I think that would work (untested).